# Is it possible to track changes to a variable in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, recursion

Say you have a recursive function that changes part of a global variable.

Eg. Global variable is a 3D array from 1 to 20 (i.e `(:,:,20)`, and in one recursion `(:,:,3)` and `(:,:,5)` are changed, and in the next recursion `(:,:,7)` and `(:,:,8)` are changed. Is it possible to see when each value for one of the elements is created, so see that in the first recursion the 3rd and 5th element were assigned a value, and in the second recursion the 7th and 8th were?

Comment: Sure, just make a separate vector `t=zeros(1,20)` and populate it with the recursion count when an element is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways I can think of.

1. Pass an extra argument to your function that acts as an accumulator and return this at the end. This is standard recursion practice if you're dealing with recursion so I won't explain further (though happy to if you ask). If you haven't dealt with accumulators before, then I'd avoid this as it's not the simplest concept to wrap your head around.
2. Append to a global variable from inside your function that acts as a counter and keeps track of what you want it to.
3. Alternatively, create a `persistent` variable inside your function to act as the counter instead. You can either return this all the way back to the first call (as you would with an accumulator), or use it to update a global variable outside your function.
4. You can avoid globals if you're happy to make your recursive function a closure returned by a generator function, such that it has state relating to your counter variable.

Happy to expand on any of the above.

Comment: Also, just pointing out that although in theory it's possible to perform simple recursion in matlab, matlab is not a language optimised for recursion and for non-trivial problems is very likely to run out of memory. Unless this is a trivial problem / assignment, it might be worth thinking of alternative vectorised ways to do this instead.